# Refrescar widget cada segundo y mostrar nuevos datos obtenidos desde Api en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, refresh

Soy nuevo en Flutter y estoy practicando un poco... Pero estoy teniendo un problemita. Estoy haciendo un chat que recibe los mensajes desde un Api, pero necesito que los mensajes que se envian y se reciban se muestren en tiempo real. Los mensajes se insertan correctamente pero para ver los mensajes nuevos debo salir del chat y volver a entrar para que se actualicen y se agreguen los nuevos. Lo que quiero es que el widget que muestre los mensajes se actualice por si solo cada x segundo.

Esto me estaba funcionando en un primer momento, pero dejo de funcionar.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        _createFloating(); //este es el metodo que quiero que se actualice cada segundo
        print('reload');
      });
    });
  }

 

Widget _createFloating() {
  return TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), builder: ((context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('${DateTime.now()}'),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 24),
                child: Column(
                  children: List.generate(
                    textt.length,
                    (index) {
                      if (chatNivel[index].toString() == 'Cliente') {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                  minHeight: 30, minWidth: 100),
                              child: Card(
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                semanticContainer: true,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10))),
                                elevation: 0,
                                color: AppColor.primary,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      textt[index].toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                        5,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                  minHeight: 30, minWidth: 100),
                              child: Card(
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                semanticContainer: true,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10))),
                                elevation: 0,
                                color: AppColor.primary,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      textt[index].toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                        5,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _buildCommentBox());
  }));
}
```

Comment: Buenas. ¿Podría por favor no abrir dos preguntas iguales? Sí tienes que aportar algo más de información, edita la primera. Deberías eliminar está pregunta y editar la anterior.

Comment: Micio, tienes que implementar un Listener en tu API que escuche los cambios en tu base de datos. Te invito a mostrar más acerca de la API que utilizas para ayudarte a implementarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de 2 maneras:

- Hacer un longpoll a la API cada x tiempo para comprobar los mensajes (aunque es poco eficiente).
- En tu API implementar algo como socket.io, que esté constantemente enviando cambios cuando llegue un nuevo mensaje, de esta forma en la App solo debes crear un listener de ese servicio o darle manejo con el gestor de estados que estes usando.